# Browser stop working when i am downloading big files

Tags: internet, browser

I am on mac leopard, and when i am downloading big files using igetter, like yesterday i was downloading 2GB of file, during this time firefox and safari stop working, why it is so and how i can fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a mac user, but it's possible that the download is so efficiently done that it's using up all you bandwidth. The only solution would be to throttle down the download speed when you wish to use the internet. I quote from the [iGetter](http://www.igetter.net/iGetter.html) site:

> iGetter has a Speed Limit function
>   which allows you to download files and
>   still use your web browser without
>   loss of performance.

Comment: Well i use that feature but it's not working.

Comment: Try to throttle it some more, until you reach a workable level.

Answer (score 0):

As harrymc said, it sounds like your internet connection is getting bottlenecked. Either set a limit on iGetter or get a better connection.

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind an ADSL? If you download with high speed, the [TCP ACK packets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) can fill up your upload bandwith. therefore, no downloaded TCP packets can be acknowledged and the browsing (and other things you do over the web) get terribly slow.

One option to get around this is to prioritise all outgoing TCP segments with the "ACK" flag set.